# Can we create more number of SKUs in Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

What's the maximum number of SKU that we can create in Google Play Store? Is there any limitation to create SKU in Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

I developed app for Play Market(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim.finansia). There are about 80 SKUs. I think no limit for sky.